# Illegal argument bcrypt js - mongodb & node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When i trying to add new user by route via Postman, using syntax like:

```
  {
    "name":"Test Name",
    "email":"testmail@gmai.com",
    "username":"test123",
    "password":"3214"
}
```

console response me an error: "Illegal arguments: undefined, string"
and postman says "could not get any response"

My code example (user.js):

```
    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    });

    const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
};
```

api.js:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
        } else {
            res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
        }
    });
});
```

I want to use bcrypt, how to fix it?

EDIT: whole error log:

```
    C:\Users\ajaks\Desktop\meanproject\server\models\user.js:38
            if(err) throw err;
                    ^

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (C:\Users\ajaks\Desktop\meanproject\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at Object.bcrypt.hash (C:\Users\ajaks\Desktop\meanproject\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:220:13)
    at bcrypt.genSalt (C:\Users\ajaks\Desktop\meanproject\server\models\user.js:37:16)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\ajaks\Desktop\meanproject\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:153:21)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: @AyushGupta what you mean by "stack trace"?

Comment: I mean the whole error, along with the stack trace showing which file and line the error occured at

Comment: how did you require `User` in api.js. Please post that code too

Comment: @AyushGupta I added whole error log.

Comment: @Aabid I require User in api via const User = require('../models/user');

Comment: It looks to me like `req.body.password` is `undefined`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin do you see reason for that? It's cause callback function for addUser?

Comment: Well it appears to be the first property that actually gets read from `req.body`, so my *guess* would be that your [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) isn't configured correctly. I suggest logging out `req.body` as the first line of your /register handler to confirm either way.

Comment: @KirkLarkin well, I was sending request body by Postman in plain text type (instead of JSON). There is a select field to defining it.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in creating of `addUser` function. To create a custom function inside mongoose model need to use `statics`

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

UserSchema.statics.addUser = function(newUser, callback) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Now it will work. For more information how to create custom function inside mongoose models refer this 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

You can also read about the how `module.exports` work in `nodejs`
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/